# Could a faulty switch cause upload speeds for some to be slow?

Tags: networking, performance, switch, network-speed

We have recently switched our MSP which has caused a lot of problems with our network, but most of that is fixed and we've got one issue remaining: Half the people in our office have poor upload speeds of about 2kb/s and good download of 600mb/s, the other half have both good upload and download speeds- 300mb/s up, 600mb/s down. We've been told the poor upload speeds for some is because of a faulty switch and we need a new one. I think it's a bit coincidental that the switch fails at the same time we've changed MSPs and have had all these other network problems. It also strikes me as weird that the faulty switch only affects upload speeds - in my eyes it should fail altogether or be equally consistent with poor download speeds. The bad upload speeds is a problem on both WAN and LAN.

Has anyone got any thoughts on this?

Comment: **Could a faulty switch cause upload speeds for some to be slow?** - Anything is possible. Assuming the new MSP is telling you the switch needs to be replace, wy not let the new MSP replace the switch under the caveat that if it doesn't resolve the problem they'll put the original switch back in place and won't bill you for the switch or the labor?

Answer (score 0):

A faulty switch can cause all sorts of problems - but as you wrote, it's not all too likely to fail in a weird way at that exact time.

You can simply run a performance test between different nodes or ports on your LAN, e.g. using iperf3. If that doesn't show poor performance a switch fault becomes rather remote.

Of course, with a managed switch you'd have error counters indicating specific problems. With an unmanaged switch you can only check the error counters on the connected hosts.